# Unable to install updates ("Error Broken count >0")

Tags: 16.04, package-management, updates

When trying to install updates via Software Updater I get the following message:

```
"The package system is broken Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f"
```

Also, Software Updater crashes.

I would like to do as the above message says and disable third pary repositories, but in Software & Updates there is no option that (explicitly) mentions "third party repositories".

In the top right corner of my screen is a do-not-enter sign - clicking it shows another message saying an error occurred (`"Error Broken count >0"`).

Maybe it is related to Chromium Web Browser, because in the crash report it says

```
Title: update-manager crashed with chromium-browser-l10n in_show_transaction(): Depends: chromium-browser (>= 59.0.3071.109-0ubuntu0.16.04.1291) but 58.0.3029.110-0ubuntu0.16.04.1281 is installed
```

I thought deselecting Chromium Web Browser in Software Updater might let me install other updates but I cannot deselect it. I can deselect everything else.

I tried uninstalling the browser but this did not help.

Comment: Third party repos can be deselected from settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software, just uncheck the ones that could be causing the problem and try again. To clarify, have you actually run `sudo apt-get install -f` in the terminal? That may resolve some problems.

Comment: @brndn2k : Ok, running `sudo apt-get install -f` fixed it. I didn't try that, because I was unsure if that was meant as step two after disabling third party repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [brndn2k](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936788/unable-to-install-updates-error-broken-count-0#comment1484435_936788) suggested, running `sudo apt-get install -f` fixed it.